# Importing an Angular2 application into Phoenix-framework

Tags: node.js, npm, integration, angular, phoenix-framework

I am currently working on two related projects. One is a Phoenix based website and API, while the other is an Angular2 application that among other things uses the API provided by Phoenix. I now want the Angular2 application to be used by the Phoenix project. The problem is that I don't know what the best approach is. I am very new to Angular2 and NPM, and know very little of how it actually works outside of basic usage. These are the ways I can think of solving my problem:

1. Put the Angular2 project into the Phoenix project, making it one project. I have no idea how to do this, but I will probably get there through trial and error as both use Node.js so it should be doable.
2. Publish the Angular2 project to NPM, and then import it to the Phoenix project. How much work would be needed on the Phoenix side? Would it be the same as just running the index.html in the Angular2 project? Would I need some kind of Angular2 "shell" around it?
3. Run the Angular2 application as it's own thing, and just link to it through the Phoenix website.

Importing it as a node module sounds like the best approach, but can it be done for full applications, or is it intended for support libraries only?

Comment: Any updates on this one, it would be really nice to use webpack or brunch to work with phoenix

Comment: I just ended importing them through the vendor as i stated in the answer below. However I am not happy with this solution, so did not accept it as an "answer". Will probably come back to it later at some point. Currently not a priority

Comment: I also have been doing some efforts to make it work but failing hope one of us makes this possible soon

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if this is the "right" way to do it but this is what I did in the end:

I compiled my entire Angular2 project into app.js, vendor.js, and common.js, I then moved it all to web/assets/. After that I simply created a new html and referenced the files in question.

The biggest challenged was finding something to compile it all into these 3 files. I ended up using a stripped down version of: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: Hey, working on doing the exact same thing. Would you happen to have a repo with your trimmed down version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to leverage brunch.io, which ships with phoenix to handle your front end dependencies. There are skeletons which are essentially templates that create different front end configs but I don't see one that provides angular2. In this case I would say use bower to install the js packages you want ie:

```
bower install -S angular2
```

With this you can use brunch as a processing pipeline and it will handle minification, linting etc. and you will still be working within the "recommended" approach to managing front end assets in Phoenix.